# How to tell CMake to include file in parent directory's sibling's subdirectory for add_executable()?

Tags: c++, cmake

Say I have a project directory like this:

```
ProjA
    build
    source
        file1.h
        file1.cpp (#includes file2.h)
ProjB
    build
    source
        file2.h
        file2.cpp
```

How do I tell `add_executable()` in CMakeLists.txt to add `file2.h?`

Comment: Why would you `#include` an implementation (`cpp`) file?

Comment: Oh I think I meant `#include file2.h`

Comment: I think you're looking for [TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) though I'm not sure. That or TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES.

Comment: What is my target?

Comment: Should be whatever `project()` name is given. CMake isn't my strongest, just going off some of the files we have around. I could be completely wrong. Possibly need a super CMake file above those two projects that `add_subdirectory()` each of them.

Comment: Where is your `CMakeLists.txt` located? Do you have a `CMakeLists.txt ` in each project root folder, or is `ProjA` and `ProjB` part of the same project, and you have a `CMakeLists.txt` at the same level as the two folders?